# parsing string from urlencode and then loop

Tags: json, node.js

i am sending following text in body parameter

```
    [{"full_image":"alskdfhlkjasvbuialsdvlasljkvbaslvjhbalfdghbakjldfgjlajkshfiuqr","type":"jpg"},{"full_image": "alskdfhlkjasvbuialsdvlasljkvbaslvjhbalfdghbakjldfgjlajkshfiuqr","type":"jpg"}]
```

and then parsing it `JSON.pasre`but i am unable get get `lenght` and loop the json. following is the code.

```
    var images = req.body.images;
    JSON.parse(images, function(key,value){

        var counter = key.length;
        var seaWeedPicture = {};
            var base64FullImage = value;
            seaweedfs.write(new Buffer(base64FullImage, 'base64')).then(function (pic) {
                var seaWeedPicture = {
                    picture: config.seaWeedURL + '/' + pic.fid
                };

            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.format({
                json: function () {
                    res.send({
                        status: 200,
                        data: []
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

the generated error is `[TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string]`

Comment: i jsut want to loop the json, write file with `seaweedfs` and return its urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can get length by `Object` constructor

```
var length=Object.keys(images).length;
//Do your loop with `length`
console.log(Object.keys(images).length);//2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var record = [{"full_image":"alskdfhlkjasvbuialsdvlasljkvbaslvjhbalfdghbakjldfgjlajkshfiuqr","type":"jpg"},{"full_image": "alskdfhlkjasvbuialsdvlasljkvbaslvjhbalfdghbakjldfgjlajkshfiuqr","type":"jpg"}]

console.log(record.length);
for(var i=0;i<record.length;i++){console.log(record[i]['full_image']);}
```

Do like this: